# How can I import Web3 in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, web3js

I am trying to import Web3 in jmeter using component JSR223 Sampler by command:

```
load("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js");
```

but I got an error:

> ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "window" is not defined in https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js

How can I use Web3 in Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [`Window` interface documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)

> The Window interface represents a window containing a DOM document; the document property points to the DOM document loaded in that window.

the `window` object is something belonging to the web browser, you don't have it in [Nashorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)) implementation.

The only way to use the library is using a real browser, JMeter can be integrated with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework via [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered/)